# php mod_rewrite issue with greek characters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Guys this is driving me crazy..

I am amateur in the mod_rewrite topic.. I really need your help over here..

I would like to perform the following change.

```
blahblah.com/services/index.php
```

to

```
blahblah.com/υπηρεσίες
```

where "υπηρεσίες" is the greek translation for services. I need that for SEO purposes.

Any recommendations/solutions would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Do you experience the issue with greek characters particularly? Would you implement what you want if it was `blahblah.com/foobar` without greek?

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteRule FROMSTRING TOSTRING` yet? Else use one of the hundreds 08/15 non-existent-path-RewriteRules and handle the pathname in a php dispatcher script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite, try adding this to your .htaccess file in your document root. You need to use unicode regular expression for **υπηρεσίες** (e.g. \x##\x##):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\xCF\x85\xCF\x80\xCE\xB7\xCF\x81\xCE\xB5\xCF\x83\xCE\xAF\xCE\xB5\xCF\x82/?$ /services/index.php [L]
```

This will make it so when someone requests `blahblah.com/υπηρεσίες` or `blahblah.com/υπηρεσίες/`, they get served `blahblah.com/services/index.php`

Comment: what tool did u use to make the conversion?

Comment: I entered it into my address bar and directed it at a local copy of apache, and then looked at the logs. Though I'm sure there's more "official" ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([α-ωΑ-Ω0-9-/]+).html$ your-page.php?url=$1
    RewriteRule ^([α-ωΑ-Ω0-9-/]+).html/$ your-page.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Mind to add some explanation?